# multiple cascading combobox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I have a combobox that I fill initially with products. Those products are filterable by Category, Subcategory(not relationated with Category), and TradeMark.

I want to use cascading combo box, but, those solution works with two or more combo box that are relationated.

What can I do?

Comment: Sorry I don't really get what you mean. Do you wish to achieve some kind of filterable combobox? and only just 1 combobox?

Comment: I have four combobox, the 4th combobox are filterable by the others three, and the others three combobox do not have relation between then.

Answer (score 0):

So, If I understand correctly, what you want is to be able to filter the 4th combo with the selections from the first 3 combos, right?

If so, Telerik has a demo on filtering [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/combobox/api.html)

But, for the sake of it, you can always do like this:

```
$("#combo4").kendoDropDownList({
        autoBind: false,
        optionLabel: "Choose one",
        dataTextField: "Description",
        dataValueField: "ID",
        dataSource: {
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "<yourURLhere>",
                    data: function () {
                        return { 
                                combo1_val: $("#combo1").val(),
                                combo2_val : $("#combo2").val(),
                                combo3_val : $("#combo3").val(), 
                           };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Your url should be some kind of method where you filter the data by those 3 values (combos 1,2,3)

Hope it helps!